# Remove column while making a subset

Tags: r, subset

I want to remove column 18 while making a subset from a larger data frame

```
sub1 <- subset(dt6,ID == 51282 & [,-18])
```

dt6 is the larger subset. I can't remove column 18 by name because the name differs between files.

With above code I get error message :

> Error: unexpected '[' in "sub1 <- subset(dt6,Institutnr_fond == 51282
>   & ["

Comment: Move the `[,-18]` outside of `subset(...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
subset(dt6, subset = ID == 51282, select = -18)
```

The `select` argument is for column selection.  And you don't have to name the arguments if you put them in the right order ...

```
subset(dt6, ID == 51282, -18)
```

And as always, you could just as easily use standard data frame subsetting.

```
dt6[dt6$ID == 51282, -18]
```